# Using wildcard for Parameters with Joins, MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, parameters, wildcard

I have 2 databases where the entries should be equal, but unfortunately one database has some extra spaces in it.

My b.ACCTNO parameter have proper records, an example like "AAA", but a.Account will have it as "_AAA" where the underscore is a space.

I'm trying to use wildcards in my join statement to get it to match. No syntax issues but the wildcards don't seem to work at all.

```
From AR_Open_Query as a inner join GuAccount as b ON b.ACCTNO like ("*" & a.Account)
```

The above code, I get less results then without a Join due to the spacing in records not matching with the non-spaced records.

```
ON b.ACCTNO = a.Account
```

If I do not use wildcards like this, I actually get slightly more results, but 
not achieving what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions? And thank you in advance.

Comment: `ON b.ACCTNO like ("*" & a.Account & "*") OR a.Account like ("*" & b.ACCTNO & "*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply using the `Trim()` function instead? I have had good results with that in the past.

```
From AR_Open_Query as a inner join GuAccount as b ON b.ACCTNO = Trim(a.Account)
```

Comment: If you are not using wildcards you don't need `LIKE`, just use `=`. It will be faster.